# What does this module declaration on service works for testing but not for something else on AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am working on a fairly complex angularjs app. I have a service that I want to test via karma+jasmin; but if it works fine for testing, it crashes the app and visceversa (if the app works, the test fails).

The only line that changes is this one on the service declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('inspinia', []); //test works - app crashes
var app = angular.module('inspinia'); //app works, test crashes
```

Error when test fails:

```
$ karma start
03 02 2016 22:56:35.038:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
03 02 2016 22:56:35.041:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine.
03 02 2016 22:56:35.042:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
03 02 2016 22:56:35.144:DEBUG [karma]: List of files has changed, trying to execute
03 02 2016 22:56:35.144:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
03 02 2016 22:56:35.149:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js"
03 02 2016 22:56:35.150:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"
03 02 2016 22:56:35.150:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/ngStorage.min.js"
03 02 2016 22:56:35.150:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app.js"
03 02 2016 22:56:35.150:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services"
03 02 2016 22:56:35.150:DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services-tests"
03 02 2016 22:56:35.153:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.19 server started at http://localhost:9876/
03 02 2016 22:56:35.158:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
03 02 2016 22:56:35.158:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /tmp/karma-22744193
03 02 2016 22:56:35.161:DEBUG [launcher]: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /tmp/karma-22744193/capture.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.269:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
03 02 2016 22:56:35.279:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.315:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket /#p4GAtSgYr6JygWKCAAAA
03 02 2016 22:56:35.329:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=p4GAtSgYr6JygWKCAAAA
03 02 2016 22:56:35.401:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#p4GAtSgYr6JygWKCAAAA with id 22744193
03 02 2016 22:56:35.401:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 22744193) captured in 0.248 secs
03 02 2016 22:56:35.401:DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing
03 02 2016 22:56:35.408:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: 

03 02 2016 22:56:35.411:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
03 02 2016 22:56:35.415:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?391e45351df9ee35392d2e5cb623221a969fc009 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.415:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.415:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.416:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app.js?eb7b94b12612a8224fa3e53352074dd486839a7a /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.416:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.417:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.417:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?4a7da64f416169520c9d5c43b5a7feac6bde9104 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.417:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.417:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.418:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app-services/authentication.service.js?e29ac74d743ad6ed152315f8e02120a82d82e77b /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.418:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/authentication.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.419:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/authentication.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.419:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app-services/flash.service.js?2f379ae1f884b24f952a237a8f08da435496e318 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.419:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/flash.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.420:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/flash.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.420:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?3030709c83121e1b2ca4d1e657306b834fc13350 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.420:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.421:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.421:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/angular/angular.js?fa0d4b85854663a64407ea33e2b58bf05097db6c /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.421:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.421:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.431:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?e2829afc9f48dbc70d62e76c093673c90c0b575a /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.431:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.432:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.433:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/angular/ngStorage.min.js?a34e7d4a74c2178e0ad53f22b1a54c9990d4f754 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.433:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/ngStorage.min.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.433:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/ngStorage.min.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.434:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app-services/product.service.js?ca614815bdff50e4e2a9bda4589cd7821dee9a09 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.435:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/product.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.435:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/product.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.435:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app-services/user.service.js?b8609883742ce66f0f9b737cc39175e29dad275d /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.435:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/user.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.436:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/user.service.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.436:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app-services/user.service.local-storage.js?4ec7890d764873e39fe32b714172879e88bf5945 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.436:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/user.service.local-storage.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.436:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services/user.service.local-storage.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.437:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/js/app-services-tests/product.service.test.js?c6dfbaff24458a7be8479a1d495fdd769756f5f2 /
03 02 2016 22:56:35.437:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services-tests/product.service.test.js
03 02 2016 22:56:35.437:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/app-services-tests/product.service.test.js
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ProductService can get an instance of my service FAILED
    /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4116:53
    forEach@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:323:24
    loadModules@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4076:12
    createInjector@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4002:22
    workFn@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2506:60
    /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4116:53
    forEach@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:323:24
    loadModules@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4076:12
    createInjector@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4002:22
    workFn@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2506:60
```

Error when app crashes:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at angular.js:63
    at assertArg (angular.js:1575)
    at assertArgFn (angular.js:1585)
    at angular.js:8416
    at angular.js:7590
    at forEach (angular.js:331)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7577)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7073)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7076)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:6952)
```

This is a highly simplified version of my service (but enough in order to reproduce the error):

```
var app = angular.module('inspinia', []);
app.factory('ProductService', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$localStorage', function($rootScope, $http, $localStorage){
    this.SayHi = function(){
        return "Hi";
    };
    return this;
}]);
```

And this is my unit test (also simplified):

```
describe('ProductService', function () {
    beforeEach(module('inspinia'));
    beforeEach(module('ngStorage'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($localStorage) {
        $localStorage = $localStorage;
    }));
    it('can get an instance of my factory', inject(function(ProductService) {
            expect(ProductService).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

So I have two questions:
1. What is the difference between my module's declarations
2. What could I do to have my test and app working?

Comment: Maybe part of your simplification for SO, but should app.factory('PrService'...) be app.factory('ProductService'...)?  Also, what version of angular?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo at the moment of write the question. Nope, I am using Product Service (Edited the question).

Comment: There is no GetAll method on ProductService. The errors miss stack trace which may help to detect the problem, 'ProductService can get an instance of my factory FAILED' isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that line as it wasn't relevant to the example, also I added the stack traces to the question.

Comment: Still not clear why exactly it fails, there are no exceptions in spec output. But `angular.module('inspinia')` implies that the module was already defined with `angular.module('inspinia', [])` somewhere else. Was it?

Comment: Yes, there is a config file, and that module is passed several dependencies, such as ngStorage.

Comment: still missing some context in your stripped down example.  for example, the real error mentions "MainCtrl" which is not in your sample code.  I suggest you put a working / non-working example up on Plunkr or something.

Comment: It fails on every controller, if I remove the MainCtrl, it fails on HomeCtrl, if I remove the HomeCtrl it fails on the ProductCtrl, etc. That's why I didn't include any additional scripts. But I'll try to reproduce it on Plunkr. Thanks.